# Ruby count adjacent duplicate elements in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given an array, say `%w[ a b c a a b b c c c]`. The method should return 3, as it is the maximum quantity of adjacent duplicates ( 3 'c' )

This is what I came up with so far:

```
def check_quantity_of_same_adjacent_elements(array)
  max = 0
  array.each_index do |i|
    max += 1 if array[i] == array[i+1]
  end
  max
end
```

but it obviously don't work as it returns the number of all duplicates

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Is this a homework question? (There's a `homework` tag if so)

Comment: No, it's not a homework, it's an actual task I have to accomplish in order to create slot machine in ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%w[a b c a a b b c c c].chunk{|e| e}.map{|_, v| v.length}.max #=> 3
```

Comment: Can you explain me what purpose does the underscore there serve? I only can find map.with_index which takes two parameters

Comment: `_` is known as a "black-hole" variable. It's used to assign values to, but never retrieve them, and is useful when you know something is going to be passed but want to ignore it.

Comment: This is just a community coding convention, but it has been so widely adopted that even the Ruby implementations were modified to nut generate an "unused parameter" or "unused local variable" warning for identifiers starting with an underscore.